# Reading 3-dimensional data from many files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I have many text files with data written in such a structure:

```
#ABTMTY 
   mdjkls   993583.17355
   ebgtas   899443.47380
   udenhr   717515.59788
   paomen   491385.80901
   gneavc   275411.91025
   wesuii   119744.95306
   ploppm    59145.56233

#MNTGHP
   mdjkls   5668781.68669
   ebgtas   3852468.72569
   .
   .
   .
```

and the name of the file  "ang_001", "ang_002" etc. is the third dimension. I have to make a 3D matrix of values, but I don't know how to make this in an efficient way.

I thought about such an approach:

1. Iterate over each file so I can get filename (variable_1)
2. Go to each file and find how many times 6-capital-letter code appears (variable_2) appears. Then cut out the "table" parts with small letter code (variable_3) and value, and paste them into a DataFrame.
3. Have a series of DataFrames, each corresponding to different variable_1.

For now I tried to iterate over a single file. First I count the occurrences of this 6-capital-letters code, as all of them start from "#":

```
for ang_file in ang_all:
    file = open(ang_file, "r")
    text = file.read()
    count = text.count("#")
```

Then I iterate over the tables with data that are in this single file. Each new table I add to the main DataFrame. Each table length is 101 lines and they are separated by a single space.

```
n = 0
for header in range(count):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv("ang_001.txt", delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace = True, nrows= 101, skiprows = 1 + n*header, names = ["code", "value"])
    df = pd.concat([df, df_tmp], axis = 0)
    n += 100
```

The problem is that there are around 1000 such files, and each of them is above 20 MB. This one short loop already took a lot of time to complete, and I'll still have to work somehow with the data in the DataFrame. Is there a better way to do it? Are there any Python packages that specialize in efficient reading text files?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.4.0 of Pandas, there is a new experimental engine for [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), relying on the Arrow library’s CSV multithreaded parser instead of the default C parser.

Also, you should avoid concatenating inside the for-loop and append to a list instead.

So, refactoring your code like this should speed things up:

```py
n = 0
dfs = [df]
for header in range(count):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(
        "ang_001.txt",
        engine="pyarrow",
        delim_whitespace=True,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        nrows=101,
        skiprows=1 + n * header,
        names=["code", "value"],
    )
    dfs.append(df_temp)
    n += 100

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```